# Pandas: How to prepare a Multi-Label Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have function `get_tags` which returns a list of labels corresponding to a text:

```
def get_tags(text):
    # Do some analysis and return a list of tags
    return tags
```

E.g., `get_tags(text1)` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` while `get_tags(text2)` returns `['a', 'b']`

I also have a pandas DataFrame `df` with columns `[text, a, b, c, d, e, f]` having 500,000 rows. I want to fill 1's as labels to the text in a particular row. Right now, I am executing

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, get_tags(df.loc[i, "text"])] = 1
```

This is painfully slow. I can use `joblib` but before that I want to see the most efficient way to achieve this.

Before execution,  `df` looks like this:

                       `text  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  text having a, b, c tags  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  text having a, c tags     0  0  0  0  0  0
2  text having a, b, f tags  0  0  0  0  0  0`

After the execution, it should look like this:

                       `text  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  text having a, b, c tags  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  text having a, c tags     1  0  1  0  0  0
2  text having a, b, f tags  1  1  0  0  0  1`

Comment: You can use `df['label'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: get_tags(x))` and from label column you can split the tags into corresponding columns

Comment: Please show sample of data as well.

Comment: Sometimes is faster to do your calculation outside of pandas and then put the data back in your dataframe. But in you case get_tags could also be your bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

df is your raw dataframe,
we can also use MultiLabelBinarizer in sklearn.preprocessing.

Before execution, df is:

```
--------------------------
|   | text | labels       | 
--------------------------
| 0 |  A   | a, b, c      |
--------------------------
| 1 |  B   | a, c         |
--------------------------
| 2 |  C   | a, b, f      |
--------------------------
```

do as follows:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb_result = mlb.fit_transform([str(df.loc[i,'labels']).split(',') for i in range(len(df))])
df_final = pd.concat([df['text'],pd.DataFrame(mlb_result,columns=list(mlb.classes_))],axis=1)
```

After execution, df_final is:

```
------------------------------------
|   | text | a | b | c | d | e | f | 
------------------------------------
| 0 |  A   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
------------------------------------
| 1 |  B   | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
------------------------------------
| 2 |  C   | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 
------------------------------------
```

df_final will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this speeds things up but it should work:

```
for i in ['a','b','c','d','e','f']:
    df[i] = [(1 if i in element else 0) for element in df['text'].apply(get_tags)]
```